# Node js remove old files in a Directory

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I want to remove some files in a directory after reaching some limits.(for example remove files if number of files more than 20)

It would be great if any automation can be done to remove those files.

**In details:**
In my case there is a uploads directory, where I'm uploading the images. For each new image, a directory is created and the image resides in the directory. So I want to keep some of the newly created or recently used directories and remove others after a certain limit(for example after reaching 20 numbers of directories). While creating new images, it'll check the limit and if exceeds the max dir limits, it'll remove the unused directories.

Note: The directories are not empty.

How can i do that using Node.js

Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: What I have done is not effective actually.
I'm counting the files in a directory and if count is greater than a max limit, I'm performing the delete operation.

But it is more expensive and slows down for more requests.

Comment: So your question is about performance? Such kind of operation is expensive anyway. Maybe you can perform this cleanup using more async approach - by `cron` or something? I mean, maybe it's not web service job to do such things? If counting files is the bottleneck maybe you want to store this value somewhere and update it when user upload/delete file?

Comment: Hi,
I have found the answer,but don't know is the correct way to do.

I have use unix command and execute using 'execSync' as follows

var filesToRemove = execSync('ls -1dt '+path.join('path_to_dir', '*')+path.sep).stdout.split('\n').splice(limit);

The ls -1dt command sort the file by creation time and remove files after a certain number(limit).

It may help someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might consider setting up a kue task:
https://github.com/learnboost/kue

Kue (or a slight wrapper/mod on top of it) is likely to be what makes it into core for our scheduled jobs down the road.

Comment: Hi,
I think you didn't get my problem. The solution you have given is something different from my requirement.

Any ways thanks for you reply...

Comment: @user1979456 Kue can be used for task scheduling-- ie. cleaning up files, much like Cron.  Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

The most widely used technique would be to have an API that can delete files in your folder. Take a look at

```
fs.unlink
```

You can get more details [here](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_unlink_path_callback)

Once you have this API, it is preferable to have a cron call this API every month or so. Take a look at

```
crontab -e
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I unlink remove only empty files/dir. I want to remove files that are not empty.

Comment: `fs.unlink` will remove non-empty files, but it can not remove non-empty directories.

Answer (score 2):

If you're running Node on a Linux server, you can use the `exec` module to execute Linux commands. For example, here is a function I use to move old log files:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

exec('mv ' + __dirname + '/log/*.log ' + __dirname + '/log/archive', 
    function(err, stdout, stderr) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error archiving log files: ' + stderr);
        } else {
            console.log('Log files archived to ' + __dirname + '/log/archive');
        }
});
```

You can use any Linux command - so you could use this approach to remove files as well.

Comment: wouldn't it be better to call an sh file that you can edit without changing the node.js code?

Answer (score 2):

I create a "cronjob" function in node.js to remove files in a folder (note child folders will be ignore)

**USAGE:**

```
// keep only 5 newest files in `logs` folder
watchAndRemoveOldFiles('logs', 5, function (err, removeFiles) {
    console.log('These files has been remove:', removeFiles);
});
```

**Full code (*you need `npm install async` to run the code*):**

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var async = require('async');

function findAndRemoveOldFiles(inputDir, keepCount, callback) {
    if(!callback) {
        callback = function (err, removeFiles) {
            // default callback: doing nothing
        };
    };

    fs.readdir(inputDir, function (err, files) {
        if(err) {
            return callback(err);
        }

        fileNames = files.map(function (fileName) {
            return path.join(inputDir, fileName);   
        });

        async.map(fileNames, function (fileName, cb) {
            fs.stat(fileName, function (err, stat) {
                if(err) {
                    return cb(err);
                };

                cb(null, {
                    name: fileName,
                    isFile: stat.isFile(),
                    time: stat.mtime,
                });
            });
        }, function (err, files) {

            if(err) {
                return callback(err);
            };

            files = files.filter(function (file) {
                return file.isFile;
            })

            files.sort(function (filea, fileb) {
                return filea.time < fileb.time;
            });

            files = files.slice(keepCount);

            async.map(files, function (file, cb) {
                fs.unlink(file.name, function (err) {
                    if(err) {
                        return cb(err);
                    };

                    cb(null, file.name);
                });
            }, function (err, removedFiles) {
                if(err) {
                    return callback(err);
                }
                callback(null, removedFiles);
            });
        });
    });
}

function watchAndRemoveOldFiles(inputDir, keepCount, callback) {
    findAndRemoveOldFiles(inputDir, keepCount, callback);
    fs.watch(inputDir, function () {
        findAndRemoveOldFiles(inputDir, keepCount, callback);
    });
}

// USAGE: watch and remove old files, keep only 5 newest files
watchAndRemoveOldFiles('log', 5, function (err, removeFiles) {
    console.log('These files has been remove:', removeFiles);
});
```

Comment: It's not working. Always return These files has been remove:[].

Comment: I just tested on my windows and my linux machines. Note that the code will not watch files in child directories of `log`. If you add more than 5 files in `log` directory the oldest one will be removed

Comment: In my case there is a uploads directory, where I'm uploading the images. For each new image, a directory is created and the image resides in the directory. So I want to keep some of the newly created or recently used directories and remove others after a certain limit(for example after reaching 20 numbers of folder). While creating new images, it'll check the limit and if exceeds it'll remove the directory.

Note: The directories are not empty.

Thanks